# How can I check if the transform reached his own original position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed;

    private Vector3 originPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        originPos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (DetectCollision.moveGate == true)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            if (transform.position != originPos)
            {
                transform.position -= Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried :

```
if (transform.position != originPos)
```

But it keep moving non stop to the left.

Then tried :

```
if (Vector3.Distance (transform.position, originPos) <= 0)
```

But then the transform is not moving at all.

I want the transform to move back to his original position and then to stop at the original position.

Comment: You might want to just check of distance between original and current is within a range as it’s not unlikely that it will be a hair out

Comment: In addition, you can check if [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) is appropriate for your use case -- it will handle overshooting natively, making your position comparison work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though for `Vector3` the [`==`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) and `!=` operators use only an approximate precision of `0.00001`, you moving each frame a distance of about `movementSpeed * 0.017` units - depending on your `movementSpeed` - it is still not unlikely that you **never** have a frame where the position lies exactly inside this `0.00001` threshold!

---

As said in the comments you should rather use [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) which prevents any overshooting

> Calculate a position between the points specified by current and target, moving no farther than the distance specified by maxDistanceDelta.

Then to make sure you really reach the `originPos` and not only a `0.00001` threshold around it I would combine [`Vector3.Distance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) and [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html).

Alternatively you can probably also use [`Vector3.Equals`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Equals.html)

> Returns true if the given vector is exactly equal to this vector.
>
> Due to floating point inaccuracies, this might return false for vectors which are essentially (but not exactly) equal. Use the == operator to test two vectors for approximate equality.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed;

    private Vector3 originPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        originPos = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (DetectCollision.moveGate)
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Mathf.Approximately(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, originPos), 0))
            // if(transform.position.Equals(originPos)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, originPos, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```